# low disk space on filesystem.root (updated)

Tags: partitioning, 20.04, kernel, filesystem

I downloaded Ubuntu 20.04 to make a Windows 10 / Ubuntu 20.04 dual-boot environment only four weeks ago, and a week ago I began to receive the warning message each time I open the system.  This seems to be an old problem on many versions of Ubuntu going back for almost a decade if not longer.  I am trying to follow the various answers from the last decade or so and they are making my head spin.

When I enter `df -h`, I get the following readout:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p6   11G  9.8G  418M  96% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop1       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/nvme0n1p1  252M   33M  220M  14% /boot/efi
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop3      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop4      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/loop5       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop7       52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop6       51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop8       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop9       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
tmpfs           1.6G   56K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

The third line shows that I have only 418M left, and 96% is being used.

When I enter `dpkg --list | grep linux-image`, here is the output:

```
/Desktop$ dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-5.11.0-25-generic              5.11.0-25.27~20.04.1                  amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-43-generic               5.8.0-43.49~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic               5.8.0-59.66~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.8.0-63-generic               5.8.0-63.71~20.04.1                   amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04              5.11.0.25.27~20.04.10                 amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

The list of kernels is pretty small.  Do I need to delete any kernel images?  Is that really the source of the problem?

When I enter `sudo apt autoremove`, nothing is removed:

```
/Desktop$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 31 not upgraded.
```

Something else that is strange is that I can't automatically connect to the Internet when I open Ubuntu 20.04; I have to open Windows first, then restart on Ubuntu in order to have an Internet connection.  The filesystem menu which should be on the upper right when I open Ubuntu is missing.  Also, the Disks app doesn't open even though it is installed.  Maybe all of these problems are connected.

I took a screenshot of my disk management readout on the Windows side, and I'm trying to upload it here:

[image: screenshot of partition]

I've tried various uses of `sudo apt autoremove`, `sudo apt-get --purge`, etc., but they are not working to restore the disk space.

What is the right way forward these days for addressing the filesystem root disk space problem?

Comment: The minimum disk allocation has been 25GB since Ubuntu 17.10 (or the 2017-October release; ie. first release using the GNOME 3 desktop); https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements   Given you haven't allocated the recommended minimum, why are you surprised you have disk space issues?   I'd recommend increasing your allocated space to the recommended minimum of 25GB, or limit what you add & maintain the system more (more regular maintenance, updating etc. is required if you have less space)

Comment: On the screenshot I posted, Windows (C) is 462 GB, and New Volume (D) is supposed to be Ubuntu and is 457.76.  Are you saying that New Volume D isn't Ubuntu?  There is another partition which is 10.99 but it doesn't have a name -- is that where Ubuntu is?  In that case what is New Volume D and did I do the partitioning wrong?

Comment: Your picture shows a windows system; I was going from the paste which shows `/dev/nvme0n1p6   11G  9.8G  418M  96% /` or a 11GB / partition where 11GB is well less than the 25GB recommended partition size for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.

Comment: Holy Cow.  I'm guessing that the 10.99 one is where Ubuntu is, since that is the total size of nvme0n1p6 in the df -h readout above.   I must have messed up in partitioning because the intent was for New Volume (D) to be Ubuntu.  Is that what happened?  How can I fix this?

Comment: New Volume (D) was supposed to be Ubuntu.  Did they get switched somehow?  Is the 10.99 one in the screenshot where Ubuntu is?

Comment: I'm not willing to advise on reading windows displays (*I use windows less than once per month*) and don't know what partitions you have used for what; but you could delete the ex-FAT (which your picture shows is currently a windows used partition) and use that space to grow the Ubuntu partition; but it will mean whatever is on it will be lost (*it appears mostly empty*), or re-install and do what you first intended correctly.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the partition process.  I didn't intend to create two huge Windows partitions, but to split the drive evenly between Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.   The ex-FAT partition is where Ubuntu was supposed to be.

Comment: I think what I should do is to shrink the ex-FAT and expand the other one "Healthy (primary partition)" on the assumption that it is where Ubuntu is.  I hope this is feasible to do.

Comment: Ubuntu cannot be installed to an exFAT file system. It is not compatible with *NIX permissions and ownership.  Do not use Windows to prepare partitions for Ubuntu. You will probably need to reinstall Ubuntu. To prepare the disk for installation, make sure that you have **unpartitioned free space**.  You can use the live session (Try Ubuntu) to delete partitions and make this space. Since you already have Windows installed, this will give you the option to use the "Install Alongside Windows" guided installation. Don't create a partition in the empty space. The installer will do that for you.

Comment: In light of the replies above, I deleted New Volume (D) and  that area is now marked as Unallocated.  Then I went over to Ubuntu and found that Ubuntu is still functioning, it was not affected by deleting D.  Windows Disk Management is not allowing me to extend the Ubuntu disk.  I'd like to extend it instead of reinstalling Ubuntu.  If I download Gparted while in Ubuntu, can I extend it from there?  Or do I need to go into Try Ubuntu from Windows?  Or something else? I installed Ubuntu "alongside Windows," but inadvertently I created 2 Windows partitions first, one of which (D:) I've now cut.

Comment: You cannot re-size an *in-use* (or *mounted*) partition, so by booting a *live* system (eg. installation media and using the "Try Ubuntu* option) only the thumb-drive or installation media will be *in-use* and you can re-size there.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it worked!  I booted Try Ubuntu from the installation USB I created when I installed Ubuntu several weeks ago.  Then I used Gparted to resize the partition.  Here is my new df -h readout:

```
~/Desktop$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.8M  1.6G   1% /run
dev/nvme0n1p4  385G  9.9G  356G   3% /
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/1988
/dev/loop1      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/66
/dev/loop2      219M  219M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/72
/dev/nvme0n1p1  252M   33M  220M  14% /boot/efi
/dev/loop3       65M   65M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
/dev/loop4       66M   66M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1515
/dev/loop5       51M   51M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/547
/dev/loop6       52M   52M     0 100% /snap/snap-store/518
/dev/loop7       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop8       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12398
/dev/loop9       33M   33M     0 100% /snap/snapd/12704
tmpfs           1.6G   24K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

And here is the new disk allocation, courtesy of Gparted:

[new disk allocation courtesy of Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUtvF.jpg)

(The revised Ubuntu partition is dev/nvme0n1p4 385G 9.9G 356G 3%.)

Also, the Internet icon has reappeared in the upper right and I was automatically connected when I opened Ubuntu just now.  I am guessing that as the partition was filling up before, Ubuntu compensated by cutting out some of the start-up activities and I could no longer connect automatically.

Anyway it looks like I am back in business now.  Thank you so much for your help!